# How to access multiple secrets from google secret manager?

Tags: node.js, google-secret-manager

I have an application which wants to access only the secrets for that application. Is there anyway to access multiple secrets instead of accessing single secret each time?

Comment: Can you show some codes you already tried and in what way they didnt work? Can you share what frameworks and or languages you use? we need more details

Comment: No, you must access each secret individually

Comment: @Luke_ In my code i was trying fetch individually thats all. I am using nodejs  with nestjs and expressjs framework

Answer (score 1):

Each secret must be accessed individually via a separate API call. You can logically group secrets using labels and then "list + access" [based on a label](https://cloud.google.com/secret-manager/docs/filtering).

At present, this is only available via the API using the querystring `filter` parameter. In the next two weeks, the SDKs will be updated and you could do something like:

```
const [secrets] = await client.listSecrets({
  parent: "projects/my-project",
  filter: "labels.app=my-app",
});

const versions = secrets.map((secret) => async {
  return await client.accessSecretVersion({
    name: `${secret.name}/versions/latest`,
  });
});
```

In the meantime, you can perform this filtering client-side. Unless you have thousands of secrets, the performance will be negligible:

```
const [secrets] = await client.listSecrets({
  parent: "projects/my-project",
});

const versions = await secrets
  .filter((secret) => {
    return secret.labels.app === "my-app";
  })
  .map((secret) => async {
    return await client.accessSecretVersion({
      name: `${secret.name}/versions/latest`,
    });
  });
```